# How can I fix this code to make collection for each user?

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an Android app for my studies. It's about babies as a general help for new parents. I have a login and registration, babylist with recyclerview and other parts of the app. I made a collection but every new user can see the same collection. How can I change my code to create a new collection for them to prevent seeing babies that you do not own? Code below is the babylist with recyclerview where you can choose a baby to go to the next screens. The collection is only here, maybe I should create it somewhere in the login activity, but I have no clue how to edit that. I was looking at tutorials, but it didn't really help.

```
package com.example.babycare.activity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.babycare.model.Child;
import com.example.babycare.adapter.ChildAadpter;
import com.example.babycare.R;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class babyList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference childbookRef = db.collection("Children");

    private ChildAadpter adapter;

    private TextView nameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby_list);

        FloatingActionButton buttonAddChild = findViewById(R.id.button_add_child);
        buttonAddChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(babyList.this, NewChildActivity.class));
            }
        });

        /*  FloatingActionButton buttonHelp = findViewById(R.id.button_help);
            buttonHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(babyList.this, HelpActivity.class));
            }
        }); */

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = childbookRef.orderBy("age", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Child> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Child>()
                .setQuery(query, Child.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ChildAadpter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                adapter.deleteChild(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ChildAadpter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                nameView = findViewById(R.id.timeSlept);
                Intent intent = new Intent(babyList.this, SelectionMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(babyList.this, "Child " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

And Login Activity

```
package com.example.babycare.activity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.babycare.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText loginEmailId, logInPassword;
    Button buttonLogIn;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private TextView forgotPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);

        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPassword.class));
            }
        });


        TextView buttonSignIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loginEmailId = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        logInPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        buttonLogIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent I = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

        buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String userEmail = loginEmailId.getText().toString();
                String userPassword = logInPassword.getText().toString();
                if (userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    loginEmailId.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                    loginEmailId.requestFocus();
                }else if (userPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    logInPassword.setError("Enter Password!");
                    logInPassword.requestFocus();
                }else if (userEmail.isEmpty() && userPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (! (userEmail.isEmpty() && userPassword.isEmpty())) {
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Not sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
}
```

Register Activity

```
package com.example.babycare.activity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.babycare.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText emailId, password, password2;
    Button buttonRegistration;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        TextView buttonAlreadyHaveAnAccount = findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
        buttonAlreadyHaveAnAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        password2 = findViewById(R.id.inputConfirmPassword);
        buttonRegistration = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        buttonRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String inputEmail = emailId.getText().toString();
                String inputPassword = password.getText().toString();
                String inputPasswordConfirm = password2.getText().toString();
                if (inputEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (inputPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    password.setError("Set your password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }else if (inputPasswordConfirm.isEmpty()) {
                    password2.setError("Confirm your password");
                    password2.requestFocus();
                }else if(inputEmail.isEmpty() && inputPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (! (inputEmail.isEmpty() && inputPassword.isEmpty() && inputPasswordConfirm.isEmpty())) {
                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, inputPassword).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "SignUp unsuccessful: "+ task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an identifier to your login if you don't have one yet. Add the identifier of the parent to each baby he owns. When fetching the baby data pass the identifier of the parent to the query so only babies that belong to the parents/logins identifier are in the result.

Identifier could be a unique numeric value, but you could also use the unique data that you use for the login, i.e. the email, a token or similar.